# Are there separable polynomials in $K[Y][X]$ with constant discriminant?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Let $A$ be a ring and $P\in A[X]$ be a monic degree $n$ polynomial.

Let $Disc(P):= Res(P,P')$ be the discriminant of $P$.

If $A=\mathbf Z$, then [Minkowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_bound) says that there are no non trivial irreducible polynomials with discriminant equal to $\pm 1$ (the units in $\mathbf Z$).

Since $\mathbf Z$ and $k[Y]$ with $k$ a field have a lot of similarities, one could naively expect that a similar result holds over $k[Y]$.
Namely: there are no non-trivial monic (*separable*) polynomials $P_Y(X) \in (k[Y])[X]$ with discriminant (as a polynomial in $X$) equal to a non zero constant (a unit in $k[Y]$).

This naive statement turns out to be not quite true: If $P(X)\in k[X]$ has non zero discriminant (in $k$) then $P_Y(X,Y):= P(X+Y)$ has same discriminant! (Thus the same holds for $P_Y(X,Y):= P(X+Q(Y))$ for $Q\in k[Y]$ any other polynomial).

However, this seems to be the only bad thing that can happen. For example, for degree 2 or 3 polynomials, one can prove that (in characteristic not $2$ and $3$, say) all polynomials $P_Y(X)$ as above are obtained by translation of a separable polynomial in one variable. For $n=2$ this is trivial; for $n=3$, this amounts to showing that there are no non constant polynomials $A, B \in k[Y]$ such that $A^2+ B^3$ is constant. However, the proofs are really *ad hoc* and made possible by the simplicity of the expression of the discriminant.

My question thus is :

How to prove that  all polynomials $P_Y(X)$ as above are obtained by translation of a polynomial in one variable in degree $>3$.
Can we somehow adapt  Minkowski's theorem?

Comment: The link on wikipedia does not work due to the ' symbol...

Comment: I fixed the link. Click "edit" on your question to see how I did it. `[link text](http://link-url)` is the standard way to format links on this site.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I promess I'll remember it!